# How to replace system font of a Galaxy Tab 7.7?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-tab, fonts

How do I replace the default system font on a Galaxy Tab 7.7, by a `.ttf` font?

Answer (score 5):

The app [Font Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.font.installer&feature=nav_other#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDYsImNvbS5qcnVtbXkuZm9udC5pbnN0YWxsZXIiXQ..) will allow you to install a font and set it as the system font. As with anything that modifies a system file, you will need to be rooted to do this.

Comment: Fonts can be install on Galaxy devices without root, using apps like: Fontomizer SP(Font for Galaxy). I want to convert an existing `.ttf` font for installing on the device.

Comment: Oh, what format does it need to install it?

Comment: And looking at that "app", it can only install without root *if* your device uses the FlipFont system, which is designed to allow a user to add their own system fonts. Most roms don't use this, so you will need root in most cases.