# How to install additional fonts?

Tags: installation, fonts

Is it possible to install additional fonts on android for use when browsing websites?
My device is rooted ICS.

Comment: Have you tried "clicking" on your assigned `fonts` tag? There are several questions dealing with this issue. Maybe some of the answers given there might fit your problem?

Comment: Seems similar to [How to replace system font of a galaxy tab 7](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/how-to-replace-system-font-of-a-galaxy-tab-7-7). I'm pretty sure that you can't change fonts for just a single app though as referenced in the answer to [Installing Custom fonts on android tablets](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11789/installing-custom-fonts-on-android-tablets?rq=1).

Comment: @ZnewmaN I don’t want to replace the system font. I want Windows font to display properly in my browser (Opera).